# boto3 working strange for string replacement while reading s3 file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

```
1. 
   var="value: REPLACE_PNAC"
   var.replace("REPLACE_PNAC", "12345", 1 )
   print ( var )
   ANS: ===> 12345

2.
   s3Client=boto3.client('s3')
   response = s3Client.get_object(Bucket=v_s3bucket, Key=v_s3key)
   data = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
   data.replace("REPLACE_PNAC", "12345" )
   print ( data ) 
   ANS: ===> This will still retain REPLACE_PNAC and will not print 12345

3.
   s3Client=boto3.client('s3')
   response = s3Client.get_object(Bucket=v_s3bucket, Key=v_s3key)
   data = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
   data.replace("REPLACE_PNAC", "12345" )
   print ( data )
```

1. Normal String replace works absolutely fine.
2. If I read the file from s3 and try to replace the string, it will not replace.
3. However, if i assign the variable value, it will work properly.

Can anyone tell me the reason, why should we explicitly assign value to a variable?

Answer (score 1):

Strings in Python are immutable, if they are to be changed it needs to happen through re-assignment: `var = var.replace('x', 'y'`. When running your first example the replacement doesn't happen, i.e. the print still prints the old value - probably an overlook or your example is just wrong.

Even the help tells that a copy is returned (and not the original gets modified):

```
>>> help('x'.replace)
Help on built-in function replace:

replace(...)
    S.replace(old, new[, count]) -> string

    Return a copy of string S with all occurrences of substring
    old replaced by new.  If the optional argument count is
    given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

>>>
```